# Can't load multiple texture on OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, textures

I'm trying to load multiple textures in openGL.
To validate this I want to load 2 textures and mix them with the following fragment shader:

```
#version 330 core

out vec4 color;
in vec2 v_TexCoord;

uniform sampler2D u_Texture0;
uniform sampler2D u_Texture1;

void main()
{
    color = mix(texture(u_Texture0, v_TexCoord), texture(u_Texture1, v_TexCoord), 0.5);
}
```

I'have abstract couple of OpenGL's functionality into classes like `Shader`, `Texture` `UniformXX` etc..

Here's an attempt to load the 2 textures into the sampler units of the fragment:

```
        Shader shader;
        shader.Attach(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, "res/shaders/vs1.shader");
        shader.Attach(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, "res/shaders/fs1.shader");
        shader.Link();
        shader.Bind();

        Texture texture0("res/textures/container.jpg", GL_RGB, GL_RGB);
        texture0.Bind(0);

        Uniform1i textureUnit0Uniform("u_Texture0");
        textureUnit0Uniform.SetValues({ 0 });
        shader.SetUniform(textureUnit0Uniform);

        Texture texture1("res/textures/awesomeface.png", GL_RGBA, GL_RGBA);
        texture1.Bind(1);

        Uniform1i textureUnit1Uniform("u_Texture1");
        textureUnit1Uniform.SetValues({ 1 });
        shader.SetUniform(textureUnit1Uniform);
```

Here's what the `Texture` implementation looks like:

```
#include "Texture.h"
#include "Renderer.h"
#include "stb_image/stb_image.h"

Texture::Texture(const std::string& path, unsigned int destinationFormat, unsigned int sourceFormat)
    : m_Path(path)
{
    stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load(1);
    m_Buffer = stbi_load(path.c_str(), &m_Width, &m_Height, &m_BPP, 0);

    GLCALL(glGenTextures(1, &m_RendererID));
    GLCALL(glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_RendererID));
    GLCALL(glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST));
    GLCALL(glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR));
    GLCALL(glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT));
    GLCALL(glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT));
    GLCALL(glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, destinationFormat, m_Width, m_Height, 0, sourceFormat, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, m_Buffer));
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    GLCALL(glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0));

    if (m_Buffer)
        stbi_image_free(m_Buffer);
}

Texture::~Texture()
{
    GLCALL(glDeleteTextures(1, &m_RendererID));
}

void Texture::Bind(unsigned int unit) const
{
    GLCALL(glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + unit));
    GLCALL(glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_RendererID));
}

void Texture::Unbind() const
{
    GLCALL(glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0));
}
```

Now instead of actually getting an even mix of color from both textures I only get the second texture appearing and blending with the background:
[image]

I've pinpointed the problem to the `constructor` of the `Texture` implementation, if I comment out the initialization of the second texture such as that its `constructor` is never being called then I can get the first texture to show up.

Can anyone suggest what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Took me a while to spot, but at the point where you call the constructor of the second texture, your *active texture unit* is still 0, so the constructor happily repoints your texture unit and you are left with two texture units bound to the same texture.

The solution should be simple enough: do not interleave texture creation and texture unit assignment, by creating the textures first and only *then* binding them explicitly.

Better yet, look into using [direct state access](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Direct_State_Access) to avoid all this binding.

To highlight the problem for future viewers of this question, this is the problematic sequence of calls:

```
// constructor of texture 1
glGenTextures(1, &container)
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, container) // Texture Unit 0 is now bound to container

// explicit texture0.Bind call
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0) // noop
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, container) // Texture Unit 0 is now bound to container

// constructor of texture 2
glGenTextures(1, &awesomeface)
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, awesomeface) // Texture Unit 0 is now bound to awesomeface instead of container.

// explicit texture1.Bind call
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1)
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, awesomeface) // Texture Unit 0 and 1 are now bound to awesomeface.
```

Comment: So there's an inconsistency between buffers and textures in the specification? Because a bound buffer is what I edit and here if the texture unit is active then the texture object originally activated with this unit is edited? Because in my `constructor` I bind a new texture after all

Comment: Your constructor calls `glBindTexture` to rebind the current target (`GL_TEXTURE_2D`) for the current texture unit (0) to the newly created texture.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Are you sure? Because I've moved the `GLCALL(glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + unit));` to the `constructor` before binding the texture and now it's working fine